# getting Nav as undefined in root page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I recently upgraded from Ionic 2 to Ionic 3. As soon as I upgraded, I am getting Nav as undefined in root page.

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component, ViewChild, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  templateUrl: `app.html`
})
export class MyApp {



@ViewChild(Nav) nav : NavController ;
  rootPage: any;
  authHandler : any;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, icon: string}>;
  urls: Array<{title: string, url: string, icon: string}>;
  contact: Array<{title: string, url: string, icon: string}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform,
              public renderer : Renderer,
              public menu: MenuController,
              public loginService : LoginService,
              public util : UtilityService,
              public statusBar: StatusBar,
              public keyboard: Keyboard) {
    this.initializeApp();
    console.log("THis is nav object :: ", this.nav);
}

//app.html
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

output in the console:

```
THis is nav object ::  undefined
```

Is something changed in Ionic 3 what I have to do In order to make that work?

Comment: Can you post your entire app.component.ts file? Are you importing Nav correctly?

Comment: @Deanmv..updated the code with the imports

Comment: You don't seem to be setting a page to rootPage as shown here - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/Nav/

Comment: I have updated the code. I had the working code before I migrated to Ionic 3. The save code was working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use ion-nav template

```
@Component({
   template: '<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
})
```

like describe here : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component

Or you can add ion-nav tag in your app.html :

```
<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content swipe-back-enabled="false"></ion-nav>
```